# Can we show $\int_0^tf(s){\rm d}B_s=-\int_0^tf'(s)B_s{\rm d}s$ for $f\in C^1(\mathbb R)$?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space, $(B_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a Brownian motion on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ and $f\in C^1(\mathbb R_{\ge 0})$. Can we show that $$\int_0^tf(s){\rm d}B_s=-\int_0^tf'(s)B_s{\rm d}s\;\;\;\operatorname P\text{-almost surely}\tag 1$$ for all $t\ge 0$? I've tried to obtain $(1)$ by the Itō formula in the following way: Let $$g(t,x):=f(t)x\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge 0\text{ and }x\in\mathbb R\;.$$ Then, $g\in C^{1,\:2}(\mathbb R_{\ge 0}\times\mathbb R)$ with $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(t,x)=f'(t)x\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(t,x)=f(t)\tag 2$$ for all $t\ge 0$ and $x\in\mathbb R$. Thus, $$f(t)B_t=\int_0^tf(s)\;{\rm d}B_s+\int_0^tf'(s)B_s\;{\rm d}s\;\;\;\operatorname P\text{-almost surely}\tag 3$$ for all $t\ge 0$. Since we would need $f(t)B_t=0$ (i.e. $f(t)=0$) to obtain $(1)$ and since this needs to be the case for *any* $t\ge 0$, I start to think that $(1)$ is wrong. However, since [Did](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6179/did) wrote that $(1)$ is trivial for $f\in C^2(\mathbb R_{\ge 0})$, I probably made a mistake.

Comment: In my opinion the answer is no because Brownian Motion is almost everywhere not differentiable.  But I'm no expert on the subject.

Comment: Is your beef with the fact that $f$ is only $C^1$ and not $C^2$? This should be explained in the question...

Comment: Why don't you address my specific request? Note that when $f$ is $C^2$, the identity is direct.

Comment: Yeah it is: Itô. (As always...)

Comment: @Did I've updated the question and deleted my obsolete comments.

Comment: And now we see that indeed a term $f(t)B_t$ was missing from your first identity (1) and that your (2) is correct.

Comment: @Did But you've said that $(1)$ would be trivial, if $f\in C^2$. What had you in mind?

Comment: Yes, and I was wrong since I forgot the $f(t)B_t$ term -- as already mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that this identity holds true. Just consider $f:=1$, then the assertion reads $$B_t = 0,$$ which is obviously not correct.

---

As @Did pointed out in a comment, Itô's formula shows that the identity $$\int_0^t f(s) \, dB_s = f(t) B_t - \int_0^t f'(s) B_s \, ds$$ holds for $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Why do you think we need $f\in C^2$? $(3)$ from the question holds for any $f\in C^1$ by the Itō formula.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Since we are turning around this point for some time now, here is a suggestion: state precisely and completely the version of Itô's formula that you know and use -- then we might be able to have productive exchanges.

Comment: @Did You can find it [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=g0LlXe5iN3AC&pg=PA174&lpg=PA174&dq=%22We+state+now+a+more+general+version+of+the%22&source=bl&ots=R_2t19bfJ9&sig=3BQdbPogPzFOqjI2fwM8Oy5k98g&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHrYjsjJHOAhWoYJoKHddHATsQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22We%20state%20now%20a%20more%20general%20version%20of%20the%22&f=false).

Comment: @0xbadf00d So, $f$ $C^1$ here yields $g:(t,x)\to f(t)x$ of class $C^{1,2}$ in your book, right? No mystery remaining, it seems.

Comment: @Did That's what I've written in the question, but you and saz are always talking about $f\in C^2$ and that's why I've started to think that I'm missing something.

Comment: @0xbadf00d My main point is that your assertion is obviously wrong.

Comment: @saz I know, but I was wondering why you and Did both meant that $f\in C^2$ would be somehow easier for proving $(3)$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d As Did pointed out, there are several versions of Itô's formula... and if you assume $f \in C^2$, you are, somehow, on the safe side. Anyway, you are right, it works fine for $f \in C^1$.